# How to override schema.graphqls file?

Tags: magento2, overrides, graph

How to override schema.graphqls file of any module? Is there any way to override schema.graphqls file of any module.

Comment: What you want to perform by override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override any modules GraphQL schema file in your own `etc/schema.graphqls`.

For example, to edit the `ProductInterface` you just need to reference it in an `etc/schema.graphqls` file:

```
# The exact line copied from Magento_CatalogGraphQl
interface ProductInterface @typeResolver(class: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\ProductInterfaceTypeResolverComposite") @doc(description: "The ProductInterface contains attributes that are common to all types of products. Note that descriptions may not be available for custom and EAV attributes.") {
    my_custom_attribute: Int
}
```

Adding the value for `my_custom_attribute` might work out to be a bit more complicated, but if you define `@resolver` for the attribute you can write a class to get it:

```
# ...
    my_custom_attribute: Int @resolver (class: "\\Company\\Module\\Model\\Resolver\\AddCustomAttribute")
# ...
```

And then, in `Model/Resolver/AddCustomAttribute.php`:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Vendor\Model\Resolver;

class AddCustomAttribute implements \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface
{

    public function resolve(\Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field $field, $context, \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null) {
        // calculate the value, you can use for example $args['product_id'] or $args['sku'] to get the product
        return 5; // always return 5
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank for your response. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am getting the $args array as empty. How can I get the product id ?

Comment: @shreyasd you can use $value['entity_id'] inside the resolve function to get product_id.